# Do weapon repairs cost less if a weapon's durability isn't fully used up?

Tags: yakuza-0

If I go to The Dragon & Tiger shop to repair a weapon or refill a gun's ammo, will it cost less money if I haven't fully used up all of that weapon's durability/ammo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
According to [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ps4/816306-yakuza-0/faqs/74451/dragon-amp-tiger):

> Repair - For a percentage of the cost of the item, you can Repair any used items in your inventory and Item Box up to full strength. **How much it costs depends on how much it was used, up to 50% of the cost of the item**. There's a CP Reward that knocks that max down to 25% of the cost of the item.